# Display contents of a file

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a file as data.html. How to display the contents of this file using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: can you be more specific???? display where???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
$('div#result').load('data.html');
```

please see details [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 1):

jquery:

```
$('#somediv').load("data.html");
```